# Avoiding std::forward and Rvalue References

Tags: c++, c++11

I recently read the [Google C++ Style Guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.html) and especially one part catched my eye.

The part about [Rvalue References](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.html#Rvalue_references) discourages from using std::forward in general and using rvalue references in other cases than defining the move assignment operator and constructor.

The only argument given for this is that these are complicated, diffcult to understand features.

Are there other arguments for avoiding these features?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. The Google style guide makes no sense for anybody except Google. And even for them it's highly questionable. The best approach to take is to forget the Google Style Guide and everything you've read in it, because it's junk.

Rvalue references are a great and wonderful thing that drastically improved C++. Not using them will consign your code to the pits of Hell. They are the number one most important feature in C++11.

Comment: That's a bold statement, chief.  Do you have any corroborating evidence you can show?

Comment: Yes, I understand that the Style Guide is meant to be used inside the company, but I thought that there would be some reasoning behind this document. I am aware that these features are very mighty and I will go on using them in my code. I was just wondering why they would avoid that feature.

Comment: @Otomo: The reasoning behind the document is that Google have a bunch of C89 and decided that since their old code was shit, their new code had to be shit too to interoperate with it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: The previous versions stated it more explicitly, but they still carry this: "In some cases there might be good arguments for changing certain style rules, but we nonetheless keep things as they are in order to preserve consistency." Of course I could also debate the merits of each rule individually with you if you prefer.

Comment: @DeadMG Doesn't make sense to me. This features don't affect the backwards compatability in my eyes. `std::forward` in particular respects the usage of Lvalue references because it is a conditional cast which leaves Lvalues alone.

Comment: @Otomo: They would, however, have to expend time training their programmers up from C89, which is time and money they can save if they don't improve their codebase with new, better features.

Comment: There seem to be quite some good rules hidden in it. So I doubt you can demolish them all. I guess the saying about the blind chickens applies to the guide...

Comment: @Deduplicator: There's nothing in the guide that's useful for an experienced C++ programmer, and if you're a new C++ programmer the shit will do far more damage than it's worth.

Comment: Hm, the line-length-limit seems sensible. Loops and switc-statements seems sensible too. Wow, a run of 3 clearly right ones... Ok, maybe 25% good, things which are hard to not do right after reading and writing a trivial amount of code... which, you are quite right, an experienced C++ programmer should already have done. Still, better to pick up a guide which is closer to 100%.

Comment: Line length.  Are there still style guides that talk about that, in an era of 1920 pixel width monitors?